# How to build a broken link checker tool?

Tags: broken-links, link-checking

I am planning to build a broken link checker tool for websites. Can you guys please let me know which tools I need to use in building the tool. I have experience in JavaScript, ExtJS, jQuery and PHP. Any help/suggestion would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at this WP plugin:

http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/broken-link-checker/ [Broken Link Checker]

It already does the job.

You could either reverse engineer it or use it as a concept tool to make your own

Comment: Thanks will try to reverse engineer this solution...